# How to set up Google ecommerce tracking for a shopping cart servicing multiple countries?

Tags: seo, google, ecommerce

Currently trying to set up GA ecommerce tracking for a shopping cart providing different pricing and tax to multiple countries. Does anyone know how to extract the tax amount from the order total for google ecommerce for multiple countries? i.e. set GA ecomm up to service/ return data for different countries?

Comment: I'm not adding this as an answer, since your question is too broad to give a detailed answer... With "_gaq.push(['_addTrans','Order-id','Store-name','Total-price','TAX-price','shipping-price','City','State','Country']);" you can pretty much add anything to add to your ecommerce tracking. Google however will not calculate anything for you depending on where the customer is located. You need to pass that to Google yourself and add the correct tax-value to the addTrans-Function. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingEcommerce#Example

Answer (score 1):

Why not setup custom variables and use them on the order thank you page so that you can send appropriate information to Google Analytics based on the order location

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

If your bank account is in the US and your website simply has a currency converter there's no need to bother with different currencies. But taxes if you charge VAT for UK residents and NYS tax for New York residents why not setup a custom variable? I still don't see why just posting the tax information wouldn't be sufficient though? If the tax amount of the total is a % does it matter which country it was for? And wouldn't you still be able to filter or sort orders by country and see tax info in your cart, excel, or even a custom report in GA?